# Error with Maven Dependencies in PlayN project

Tags: playn

I try learn PlayN, after creating Maven Project and adding dependency 
to pom.xml

```
enter code here
<dependency> 
  <groupId>com.threerings</groupId> 
  <artifactId>tripleplay</artifactId> 
  <version>1.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

I use classes from tripleplay library for menu system, such as showed 
in Showcase demo project. When run project as Java application all ok, 
but when run as html application I got errors like this

> ant.bat run-html

.... 
`[java] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Failed to get JNode
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:140)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:71)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.getType(BuildTypeMap.java:730)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.createField(BuildTypeMap.java:570)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.access$300(BuildTypeMap.java:99)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap$BuildDeclMapVisitor.visit(BuildTypeMap.java:180)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.FieldDeclaration.traverse(FieldDeclaration.java:285)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1232)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:687)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.createPeersForNonTypeDecls(BuildTypeMap.java:637)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.exec(BuildTypeMap.java:514)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.exec(BuildTypeMap.java:523)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:599)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:284)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:233)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
     [java]       [ERROR] <no source info>: public class tripleplay.ui.Interface
     [java]     extends java.lang.Object
     [java] /*   fields   */
     [java] public final [unresolved] playn.core.Pointer.Listener plistener
     [java] public final [unresolved] playn.core.Keyboard.Listener klistener
     [java] protected final [unresolved] playn.core.Pointer.Listener _delegate
     [java] protected final [unresolved] Unresolved type react.Value<playn.core.Keyboard.Listener> _focused
     [java] protected final [unresolved] List<Unresolved type tripleplay.ui.Root> _roots
     [java] protected final [unresolved] List<Unresolved type tripleplay.ui.Root> _dispatch
     [java] protected final [unresolved] List<Unresolved type java.lang.Runnable> _actions`

what wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strange that the GWT compiler would crash, rather than generating a normal error message. But it looks like you need to add the tripleplay GWT module to your GWT project.

In your game you'll have a file that's named something like:

`mygame/html/src/main/java/mypackage/mygame/MyGame.gwt.xml`

In that file, you need to add:

`<inherits name="tripleplay.TriplePlay"/>`

That will let GWT know that it can and should use the TriplePlay source code when compiling things to JavaScript.

Comment: I tried this but am now getting " GWT Module tripleplay.TriplePlay not found in project sources or resources. "

I do see the tripleplay-1.8.5.jar in Libraries>MavenDependancys so I am not sure why it cant find it.
I tried cleaning/maven cleaning/rebuilding and what not but always the same. :-/